# Best practise for GUI Components ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, actionlistener

I did a big GUI Based App and I have now many many `Action` stuff around there...
I have different `Listeneres`, like `ActionListener`, `KeyAdapters`, ... 
Everything should run threaded, so my GUI isnt freezing when do long time operations. So im using `SwingWorker` in every `ActionListener`...
Currently its working like this: I have my `JComponents`, bound on one single `ActionListener`. In this `Listener` I decide what to do, based on the `actionCommand()`. The I call a method, which contains my `SwingWorker` and the `Action` which should be performed.

Ii dont like this concept anymore, because my class is getting longer and longer and i dont have an overview about all the functionallity. So I decided to do it another way... 
I thought Factory Methods would be a great thing, but here is my problem with them: I need sometimes data from my GUI, eg: when pressing `JButton` x, what is in `JTextField` y and so on...
so what is the best practise for this? Should I just give my Factory a instance of my complete GUI? Or a `ArrayList` of `Components`? Another problem is that need to change values from my GUI, eg: press button x and then filter a `JTable`... how should i do that? 
doing it like `this = myFactory.process(this);` isnt really that what i want...

Comment: @reox I amended your post, please revert if isn't...

Comment: @reox, Focus on encapsulation. And you're right, using `SwingWorker` to handle long-running tasks exemplifies "best practice", but it's not necessary. There's other utilities (e.g. `SwingUtilities`) that you can use to ensure that Swing-related ations are posted on the `EDT`, but occur in a separate thread. Perhaps providing a small snippet of code would help us refine our answers.

Comment: @mre: so i should use a factory and should make all my fields and stuff encapsulated?

Comment: Consider to extends AbstractAction instead of implementing ActionListener interface.

Comment: yes i did, i have an own Action class, which contains my Swing Worker stuff, so when i call the method .runBackground() it will start a new swing worker with the content of myAction.process(args) - so I'm on the right way?

Comment: reox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171414/how-to-share-data-with-two2-swingworker-class-in-java/6186188#6186188

Comment: You should avoid using `KeyListener`s whenever you can (which is in 99.9% of situations), and use `InputMap` and `ActionMap` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **JGoodies Binding**: it emphasizes the use of PM (**PresentationModel**) where all the GUI state is stored (and bound to the actual GUI components).

Every **View** has an associated PM that makes the link with the domain model. PM can live without the View (but the reverse is not true).

PM should not have any GUI-related dependency (so that it is unit testable without the GUI), hence no reference to a JTextField, JButton...

However, PM normally includes `Action`s that are attached to buttons from the **View**. Actions are not actual GUI components (although they belong to `javax.swing` package.

I said "normally" because some Actions may need to display a message box, open a new window... This kind of actions should then be put in another class. Note that Karsten Lentzsch (JGoodies author) doesn't talk about this case in his presentations (this is my own way of dealing with this case).