# Starting Thread after GUI construction

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I have a program that builds the GUI in the constructor.  I need a Thread separate from the EDT to run immediately after the object in question is constructed.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: By "immediately after", do you mean that this process should be sequential?

Comment: How do you want the thread to interact with the GUI? Or is it independent?

Comment: It needs to modify data in a JTable.  The Thread in question opens up a network connection over a _very_ slow protocol, so the GUI needs to display, then the thread needs to sequentially modify entries as data streams in from the network.  So in essense: the process should be sequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is a [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)<T,V>. In the `doInBackground` method, open the connection and start fetching data. When you have enough data to update the gui, call the `publish` method. Implement the `process` method to update the gui with the new data from `publish`, and finally, implement the `done` method to notify the user when you're finished fetching data.

The Swing Worker is a generic, so when you construct it you need to provide two types: `T` and `V`. `V` is the type for the data passed between `publish` and `process` methods and `T` is the type returned by `doInBackground` and passed to `done`.

Answer (score 2):

> I need a Thread separate from the EDT

Threads are separate from the EDT so all you do is create a Runnable and then start it.

You only have to worry if the Thread updates any GUI components. If this is the case then you may want to use a SwingWorker. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

build your GUI an open a new window inside a new Runnable invoked called by: [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Answer (score 1):

you have two choises

1) wrap Thread into Runnable as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051755/java-wait-cursor-display-problem/6060678#6060678)

2) I am not very satisfy with plain SwingExecutor, then I use for that Executor and SwingWorker, monitored by PropertyChangeListener, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171414/how-to-share-data-with-two2-swingworker-class-in-java/6186188#6186188),

please carrefully with number of threads started by Executor. Executor doesn't care if SwingWorker ends or not and there still exists [Bug](http://bugs.sun.com/top25_bugs.do) where is pretty possible to overload maximum (somewhere in API) simultaneous jobs live by Executor in same time.

by this reason is there possible implements PropertyChangeListener