# Trouble with java timer?

Tags: java, swing

After advice from another thread, I've been playing with the timer class without much joy. Heres my code:

```
 public void buttonImageReveal(ActionEvent e){

        Timer gameTimer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

              repaint();
            }
          });

        String temp = e.getActionCommand();

        switch(temp){
                        case "1":
                            System.out.println("case1");                            
                            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setIcon(one);
                            gameTimer.start();
                            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setIcon(null);
                            break;
```

All I want is a 1 second gap between the image one been shown as the icon then that been removed. Only to happen once when the button is click. At the moment I just get a blank button when pressed?

TIA

Edit:

```
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          System.out.println(e);
          lastImage();

        }

      });

public void buttonImageReveal(ActionEvent e){ 

        String temp = e.getActionCommand();

        switch(temp){
                        case "1":                       
                            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setIcon(one); 
                            lastBtn = ((JButton)e.getSource()); 
                            gameTimer.start();

                            break;
```

It now doing what it should, but the timer keeps going and going, what do you do to once your finished and want it to stop?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the icon, start a timer and then immediately remove the icon. The `start()` method from the timer is almost immediately going to return and the timer will perform its task asynchronously. You'll need to do the icon removing in the `actionPerformed` method.

Comment: If I do that it seems to put it into a loop, I can't figure out why?

Comment: @EricBanderhide Can you edit your post with the updated code? Paste it behind the current code to keep the original problem clear.

Comment: Read the Timer API. There is a method that allows you to control whether the Timer fires continuously or only once.

Comment: Ah yes, set it to no repeat and its all working. Thanks G_H and camickr I've been working on this for about 2 hours with no joy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set icon to null when the timer fires. I have updated in original thread as well.
So the code should be:

```
public void buttonImageReveal(final ActionEvent e){

        Timer gameTimer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

              ((JButton)e.getSource()).setIcon(null);
            }
          });

        String temp = e.getActionCommand();

        switch(temp){
                        case "1":
                            System.out.println("case1");                            
                            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setIcon(one);
                            gameTimer.start();                                
                            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

you little bit compicated simple things,

```
      timer1 = new Timer(1000, new AbstractAction() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            random = new Random();
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    button1.setSomething(something);
                    button1.validate(); //not required for all methods
                    button1.repaint();  //not required for all methods
                }
            });
        }
    });
    timer1.setDelay(500);
    timer1.setRepeats(true);
    timer1.start();
```

examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171414/how-to-share-data-with-two2-swingworker-class-in-java/6186188#6186188) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036509/how-do-i-simulate-a-buffered-peripheral-device-with-swingworker/7049095#7049095)

don't forget to stop your `Timer#stop()`, or if you want to run this code only once then `setRepeats(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling repaint() 100ms later (should be 1000ms = 1s, I think) change the components 1s later. Do this by replacing repaint() with the changing method.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than creating a new timer could you use

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

To replace

```
gameTimer.start();
```

Comment: -1 invoking Thread.sleep() on the Event Dispatch Thread will prevent the GUI from repainting itself so you still won't won't see the initial icon.