# multithreading for java graphics

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, graphics, netbeans

I have a java application that streams raw data and draws real time plots accordingly.  this is handled by calling methods from  a class i wrote that uses the Graphics object.  i implemented algorithms in an overridden paintComponent method to generate all the plots from the most recent data.  i have other methods in my class to update variables used in the paintComponent method to draw the graphs.

in my main class, i update my graphs periodically in a timer event handler.  in the event handler i call methods from my graphs class that update certain variables, do a few calculations, and then call repaint() (which apparently is the correct way to call the paintComponent method).

my problem is, the algorithms i use in the paintComponent method can take a (relatively) long time to complete depending on the amount and resolution of my plots.  (i haven't exactly run into this problem yet, but i'm trying to address it now).  of course i wouldn't want all this graphing to hog all the processing time of my application, so i was wondering if it's possible to have "paintComponent" execute in a separate thread.

what would happen if i created a subclass in my main to run in a separate thread and simply called the graph methods i described?  would that automatically make all of those methods (including paintComponent) execute in the new thread?  or would i have to modify my graph class itself for this to work?  ideally i would like to avoid modifying my graphs class because i have already designed it to work within the NetBeans GUI builder as a JPanel, and i'd like to avoid breaking that functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to redirect paint methods to the `SwingWorker` or `Runnable#Thread` (all output to the GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater`), example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036509/how-do-i-simulate-a-buffered-peripheral-device-with-swingworker/7049095#7049095) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171414/how-to-share-data-with-two2-swingworker-class-in-java/6186188#6186188)

Answer (score 5):

There's a couple options.

One method is to use two BufferedImages, where you draw on one in separate thread, and paint from the other one, and switch as drawing completes (for what I assume is a snapshot every so often.)

A much better solution is to have a model of directly renderable data (as in the data it holds can be drawn without performing any further algorithmic work on it).

This means you will perform your alogirthms on a separate thread, calculate the values that will be used to paint, call SwingUtilities.invokeLater to update the model. The model will then only get updated on the Swing thread, and when you repaint, you have access to exactly the data you need to draw (and no extraneous data).

If this data is still so much that painting takes a long time (ie: if you're drawing charts with tons of data points), you'll send to calculate which parts of your window need repainting and fire repaint() on just that. This piece should be a lat resort however. 99% of your performance will come from moving the algorithms into a separate thread, and giving the painter access to directly renderable data.

If you look at best practices on updating a TableModel with external data, what you have is the work that gets the data occurring in a background thread (typically SwingWorker) and then posted to the actual model via invokeLater() (This is so the data doesn't get modified while your paint() is trying to read it.) and then firing appropriate events from within the model update that tell the table what cells changed. The table then knows what part of its viewport needs repainting and fires the appropriate repaint() method. During this time the background thread can continue retrieving data and adding new updates to the event queue via invokeLater.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to improve the responsiveness of the GUI you could do the lengthy work in a [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), although I don't know that doing so will speed up your application any more.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a java application that streams raw data and draws real time
>   plots accordingly. this is handled by calling methods from a class i
>   wrote that uses the Graphics object.

To complete other's answer:
you should really consider to use [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). It's a good library for drawing charts and you can modify dynamically the displayed dataset (and do a lot of more things).

Comment: yeah that was the first option i explored, but i actually didn't like the way the data was displayed.  my class is  designed specifically for modeling an oscilloscope output and already works the way i want.