# JTable binding not permitted

Tags: java, swing, binding, jtable

I've got a java.util.List bind to a JTable, if I want to refresh the table using

1. bindingGroup.unbind();
2. bindingGroup.bind();

I get this exception:

Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can not call this method on a managed binding

relative to the 2nd line above.

Below more specific code:

```
    new Thread(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    fireProgressBar(true,"working...");
                    controller.doSmoething();
                    fireProgressBar(false,"");   
                    bindingGroup.unbind();
                    bindingGroup.bind();
                    jTable1.revalidate();                        
                }
            }                
            ).start();
```

fireProgressBar is a simple method that I wrote for jProgressBar activation, nothing here is involved in binding.

the bindingGroup.bind() call throws the exception above.

I tried also with SwingUtilities.invokeLater instead of new Thread(....).start();
but I get the same issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) this code is always done in EDT, in other hands in one moment refreshed in the GUI

- wrong way inside `Runnable#Thread` without use for `invokeLater()`
- correct way inside `Runnable#Thread` wrapped into `invokeLater()`

2) you have two ways

- look at [SwingWorker and JProgressBars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)
- same way inside `Runnable#Thread` and output to the GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater()`

3) in moment that you'll to able to manage whole stepped progresses inside Background task(s), then you can implements for `Binding`

Comment: is SwingWorker the only way to get fresh data on a jTable? Is that true? Is there other ways to refresh jTable insted of using  unbind() and bind() ? Can FirePorpertyChange help me?

Comment: right SwingWorker (and Runneble#Thread too, but is easiest for workaround) can move task(s) to the background, and output fron method done() is on EDT, FirePorpertyChange is important in this processes, my examples http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A714968+swingworker here

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036509/how-do-i-simulate-a-buffered-peripheral-device-with-swingworker/7049095#7049095 are four methods how to whatever with JTable contents

Comment: Thx for Your reply mKorbel.
I don't know if can be useful for someone, but I solved the issue in this manner. 

Old list declaration was:
List<MyBean> list = new ArrayList<MyBean>();

Now the same declaration is:
ObservableList<MyBean> list = ObservableCollections.ObservableList(new ArrayList<MyBean>());

Now I don't need to do unbind() and bind() and also I don't need jTable.revalidate(); Now I have ALWAYS jTable with fresh data for everything changes made on the list.

Thx to all.