# SwingWorker - Passing parameters and returning an ArrayList<Object>

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

**NOTE:** SSCCE at the end of this question

I'm new to `SwingWorker` so please bear with me.

I'm using a GUI and when the user presses a button it executes some methods I've in another class. This class just has methods inside and I need those methods to run on their own thread. The thing is, those methods need to be passed arguments and they will also return something needed to other methods.

Something like this:

```
public class MyClass {

   public  ArrayList<Train> proccessTrain(int endTime, int startTime, ArrayList<Train> trainList)
   {
       (... I start processing data here... with sets and gets to the stationDataList array...)

       return trainList;
   }

   public int getNumberOfCrashes(ArrayList<Train> trainList)
   {
       (... I run over the array... do some comparasions... and do some sets on the Train object in the array...)

       return numOfCrashes;
   }

}
```

And my GUI Class:

```
public class MyGUI{

   MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
   ArrayList<Train> trainList = new ArrayList<Train>();

   (later on there are Train ojects added into the array)

   (when button is pressed)

       trainList = myClass.proccessTrain(20, 10, trainList);
       int numberOfCrashes = myClass.getNumberOfCrashes(trainList);
}
```

I'll also need to update the GUI and this is not an issue to me as I know I can use the `publish()` and override the `process()` method in the swing worker.
My problem is how can I return the methods to the variables in the GUI and how can I pass arguments to the methods in `MyClass.class`, as `doInBackground()` does not accept arguments.

Also, I need the swingworker to be inside the method and not on the `MyGUI.class`, so something like this (eg for the processTrain method):

```
public  ArrayList<Train> proccessTrain(int endTime, int startTime, ArrayList<Train> trainList)
{
    SwingWorker<String, Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<String, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {

            return 
        }

        protected void done() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {

        }
    };

    worker.execute();
```

If there is something missing and/or unclear please let me know, and I'll update the question.

**//////////////////////////// *_*__EDIT_*_*__ ///////////////////////////////**

As requested here is a short executable code:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private JLabel countLabel1 = new JLabel("0");
private JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel("Task not completed.");
private JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
private ArrayList<Train> trainList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Train> processedTrains = new ArrayList<>();

public MainFrame(String title) {
    super(title);

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    countLabel1.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 28));

    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.weighty = 1;
    add(countLabel1, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.weighty = 1;
    add(statusLabel, gc);

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.weighty = 1;
    add(startButton, gc);

    Train t1 = new Train();
    t1.setId(1);
    t1.setName("John");

    Train t2 = new Train();
    t2.setId(2);
    t2.setName("Mark");

    Train t3 = new Train();
    t3.setId(3);
    t3.setName("Lewis");


    trainList.add(t1);
    trainList.add(t2);
    trainList.add(t3);


    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            TrainMethods tm = new TrainMethods();

            // How can the swing worker return the array from the
            // processTrains method to this processedTrains array
            processedTrains = tm.processTrains(trainList);

            for(int i = 0; i<processedTrains.size(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Train id: " + processedTrains.get(i).getId() 
                        + " Train Name: " + processedTrains.get(i).getName());
            }
        }
    });

    setSize(200, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

private class Train
{
    String name;
    int id;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

}

private class TrainMethods
{
    public ArrayList processTrains(ArrayList<Train> trainList)
    {
        // Add here a SwingWorker to create a new thread
        // and execute the following code and update later on
        // a progress bar
        for(int i = 0; i<trainList.size(); i++)
        {
            trainList.get(i).setName("No name");
        }
        return trainList;
    }
}
}
```

What I pretend is to execute the method `processTrains` in a new `swingworker` `thread`. As you can see, the `processTrains` method requires a parameter, an `ArrayList` of Train. So my question is when I create the swing worker how can I pass the parameters, in this case the `ArrayList` of `Train`, to the `doInBackground` and how can I return the process `ArrayList<Train>` to the variable processedTrains,.

Comment: [will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6114890/714968)

Comment: Honestly I don't understand how can that code help me, it doesn't show how to pass and return the arguments the way I specified in my question. Or didn't I fully understood that answer?!

Comment: help you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), then question could be clear for all readers here, start with `SwingWorker<String, Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<String, String>() {`

Comment: don't quite understand the problem: if myClass should be controlled by the swingWorker, pass the reference to the instance into the worker?

Comment: @mKorbel I've just added the SSCCE as requested. Hope I made myself clear now otherwise let me know and I'll explain again.

Comment: @kleopatra I've edited my question, please let me know if I made myself not clear

Comment: If you don't otherwise _need_ a separate thread, use a `javax.swing.Timer`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14887457/230513).

Comment: @trashgod thank you but Timer is not really the way I should do it as my processTrains can take quite a long time to finish.

Comment: @dwnz take quite a long time to finish. == (my view as far as i understand) don't to use SwingWorker, this isn't job for SwingWorker, because you would need series of SwingWorkers, chaining a few SwingWorkers (there is still one shadowing bug), not clear but I guessing that you want to simulate more that one train on virtual railway, if yes then you would need really Swing Timer, or Runnable#Thread, util.Timer (use invokeLater for EDT) in the case that sources are accesible anywhere (DB, RMI, Socket..), note one Timer or one Thread, by default (95pct of) there isn't reason

Comment: still missing your goal, see how my [trains (twinkle_star) walking on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8614972/714968), one Swing Timer, bunch of trains, each of them representing separate Object, in this case graphics whatever, or you can to [combine a few different things together](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7049095/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel no, I don't want to simulate anything. I just have to process (check conditions and if some conditions do apply do some sets) many train objects in an `ArrayList<Train>`. And this `ArrayList` can have 50 000 or can have 1 000 000 objects. When I said it can take quite some time I mean it can take from 1 second to a couple of minutes. My goal is to process the ArrayList and return it to the variable `processedTrains`, as shown in the SSCCE. Because `doInBackground` takes no arguments and `process()` is void and `done()` is void as well

Comment: @mKorbel I also need to update the GUI as the process goes on with a status text panel or progress bar, but this is not the problem here.

Comment: @mKorbel please check this question, that SSCCE comes from this on and I think if I solve that question I can solve both of them. Thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548570/swingworker-same-variable-shows-different-values-on-sysout-and-gui