# SwingWorker - Same variable shows different values on sysout and GUI

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

Edit:
Note, this question is related to my other question here: [SwingWorker - Passing parameters and returning an ArrayList<Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544888/swingworker-passing-parameters-and-returning-an-arraylistobject)

After digging around SwingWorker and in order to try to solve that question I came up with this SSCCE code.

*End of Note*

*End of edit*

Given the following SSCCE code:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JLabel countLabel1 = new JLabel("0");
    private JLabel statusLabel1 = new JLabel("Task not completed.");
    private JLabel statusLabel2 = new JLabel("Task not completed.");
    private JLabel statusLabel3 = new JLabel("Task not completed.");
    private JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    private ArrayList<Train> trainList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Train> processedTrains = new ArrayList<>();

    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        countLabel1.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 28));

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(countLabel1, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(statusLabel1, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(statusLabel2, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 3;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(statusLabel3, gc);

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 4;
        gc.weightx = 1;
        gc.weighty = 1;
        add(startButton, gc);

        Train t1 = new Train();
        t1.setId(1);
        t1.setName("John");

        Train t2 = new Train();
        t2.setId(2);
        t2.setName("Mark");

        Train t3 = new Train();
        t3.setId(3);
        t3.setName("Lewis");


        trainList.add(t1);
        trainList.add(t2);
        trainList.add(t3);


        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                TrainMethods tm = new TrainMethods();

                // How can the swing worker return the array from the
                // processTrains method to this processedTrains array
                processedTrains = tm.processTrains(trainList);

                for (int i = 0; i < processedTrains.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Train id: " + processedTrains.get(i).getId()
                            + " Train Name: " + processedTrains.get(i).getName());
                }
            }
        });

        setSize(200, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
// Notice that it kicks it off on the event-dispatching thread, not the main thread.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame mf = new MainFrame("Yo");
            }
        });
    }

    private class Train {
        String name;
        int id;

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    }

    private class TrainMethods {

        public ArrayList processTrains(final ArrayList<Train> trainList) {
            // Add here a SwingWorker to create a new thread
            // and execute the following code and update later on
            // a progress bar
            SwingWorker<ArrayList, Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<ArrayList, Integer>() {
                @Override
                protected ArrayList doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    for(int i = 0; i<trainList.size(); i++)
                    {
                        trainList.get(i).setName("No name");
                        publish(i);
                    }
                return trainList;
                }

                @Override
                protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
                    int mostRecentValue = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
                    countLabel1.setText(Integer.toString(mostRecentValue));
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    ArrayList<Train> status;
                    try {
                        // Retrieve the return value of doInBackground.
                        status = get();
                        statusLabel1.setText("Completed Train 1 with name: " + status.get(0).getName());
                        statusLabel2.setText("\nCompleted Train 2 with name: " + status.get(1).getName());
                        statusLabel3.setText("\nCompleted Train 3 with name: " + status.get(2).getName());
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            };
            worker.execute();

            return trainList;

//            for (int i = 0; i < trainList.size(); i++) {
//                trainList.get(i).setName("No name");
//            }
//            return trainList;
        }
    }
}
```

Why the `System.Out.Println()` prints:

```
Train id: 1 Train Name: John
Train id: 2 Train Name: Mark
Train id: 3 Train Name: Lewis
```

While the user interface prints: `No Name`?
Personally I was expecting to be printed `No Name`on both.

Question 1: Why different outputs?

Question 2: How can I make it output `No Name` on both places (Sysout and GUI)?

_________________________ EDIT _______________________________

Question 3: Why on the second time I press the start button it will print `No Name`on both?

Comment: (didn't run, just looked at the code:-) you are accessing the train from both threads without any synching, so anything can happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`doInBackground()` runs, unsurprisingly, in the background. That is, it is executed in another thread. So you can not rely in the order of execution of that code, and your printing code. So the contents of `trainsList` can be modified before, after, or during the printing. You'd need to add some synchronization if you really need the results immediately (Usually you don't. That's the whole point in running the task in another thread to avoid waiting for it to be completed).

Most likely the correct solution is not have the printing code there at all, and let the `SwingWorker` do it's work the way it's intended. The results are available in a thread safe way in `done()` (and in `process()` for anything you need the quickly after the sub task is ready).

In the second run you get "No name", because you never reset the names to anything else, so they are what they have been set to in the previous run.

Comment: Understood and that is what I was expecting as the answer to the problem but I wanted to be sure :)
One more question, then how can I be sure the next time I use `processedTrains` variable it has in reality the processed `ArrayList` (I mean, it has `No Name`)?

Comment: @dwnz The process has been completed when `done()` has been called. I'm not sure *how* your program needs that information available, so I don't know what's the best way for you. A simple way would be setting a boolean flag in `done()`. (`SwingWorker` also has the `get()` method, which blocks until the task is done. In use of that one needs to be *very* careful though, exactly because it's blocking, so it can freeze the gui for long times if called inappropriately. Typically it's only called in `done()`, like you do, where it's safe).

Comment: [see OPs another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19544888/714968), I'm quite sure that isn't job for asynchrnous Future<>,

Comment: @kiheru can you show me an example with the use of a boolean flag?

Comment: @dwnz I don't know if using a flag is correct for your user case, as I don't know the conditions you need to check for the completion status. Basically that would be having a boolean field (volatile, if it needs to be available from different threads) and a `setCompleted(boolean status)/isCompleted()` setter/getter pair for it. Then calling `setCompleted(true)` in `done()`.

Comment: @kiheru search in posts by 
 [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:522444+[swingworker])  a few times explained here how SwingWorker<Xxx, Xxx> works