# Timer event runs before changing of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, debugging, timer, jpanel

I have a JFrame which contains a JPanel with the JButton "Press Me"

[image]

Pressing the "Press me" button will change to another JPanel(SecondPanel) within the same JFrame

[image]

I am facing a problem where there is a 10 second delay when i press the "Press Me" button  before the SecondPanel appears.

This 10 second delay is caused the Timer event .

I wish for the SecondPanel to appear before the Timer event start.

What is happening now is that the Timer event starts , i am waiting at the "Press Me" button for 10 seconds , before the SecondPanel appears ,

**can someone help me resolve this issue**

Thanks

**Main class used to run the project**

```
package testing;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Testing extends JPanel 
{



    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        LoginPanel lp = new LoginPanel();
        frame.add(lp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.validate();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

   static JFrame frame;
}
```

**LoginPanel class**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class LoginPanel extends JPanel
{
    LoginPanel()
    {
        Loginbtn = new JButton("Press Me");
        Loginbtn.addActionListener(new LoginButtonListener());
        add(Loginbtn);


    }

     private class LoginButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {

            SecondPanel sp = new SecondPanel();
            Utility.ChangePanel(sp);
            sp.run();
        }
    }

    JButton Loginbtn;

}
```

**SecondPanel class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class SecondPanel extends JPanel
{
    SecondPanel()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        //set deck image
        File deckfile = new File("./src/testing/Ace_Club_1_1.png"); //deck image file location

        try
        {    
          Deckimg = ImageIO.read(deckfile); //read deck image


        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {

        }

         Image scaledInstance = Deckimg.getScaledInstance(100, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
         DeckLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(scaledInstance));
         add(DeckLabel);

    }

    public void run()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                // Code to be executed
                System.out.println("HowareYou");

            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false); // Only execute once
        timer.start(); // Go go go!

        try
        {
             Thread.sleep(7000);
        }



        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {

        }

    }

    JLabel DeckLabel;
    JPanel DeckPanel;
    BufferedImage Deckimg;

}
```

**Utility class used to switch JPanels within the JFrame**

```
package testing;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Utility 
{    
    public static void ChangePanel(JPanel jp)
    {


        testing.Testing.frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
        testing.Testing.frame.add(jp);
        testing.Testing.frame.validate();


    }

}
```

Comment: there are two mistakes 1st. timer is initialized from run() and 2nd. killed by Thread.Sleep

Comment: utility is useless class use CardLayout, better is to use JLabel.setIcon(my local varibale initialized on apps startup)

Comment: scalled instalne is pretty asynchonous, carrefully with, have to calculating with possible delays (no icon is painted, only mouse hover_over repainting proper image)

Comment: @mKorbel, what's wrong with creating the `Timer` in the `run` method?  Also, calling `Thread.sleep` won't 'kill' the timer, it will still run on another thread, or is that not what you meant?

I agree that using `CardLayout` would be better, but that's not the cause of @Computernerd's issue.

Comment: @SimonC wrong idea withpossible side effects (everything inside run() can kill ....)

Comment: @mKorbel, sorry, but that doesn't make any sense.  Are you trying to say that anything running on the event thread can block the GUI?  If so then, that's still not a reason not to start a timer there.  Granted, as it stands, the `Timer` instance could be created on another thread, and only started on the event thread, but I don't the difference would be noticeable.

Comment: (but that doesn't make any sense == read Oracle tutorial swing - How to use timers)see usage of [Swing Timer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7049095/714968)

Comment: Sorry, but that's a really bad answer.

Comment: @SimonC The `run` method is adding confusion into the code, which could be consider a method part of a `Runnable` interface.  A different name would help remove the confusion. Many Swing programmers see `run` and panic

Comment: What is the purpose of `Thread.sleep(7000)`, why would you want this delay here?  What is it's purpose?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, yes, that makes sense.  I was questioning the objection to starting a `Timer` from a method called on the event thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're blocking the Swing event thread in `SecondPanel.run()` with `Thread.sleep(7000)`.  This will stop any GUI updates happening.  If you remove the sleep you should see the second panel appear before the timer fires.