# Catch Exception thrown by a SwingWorker located in a different class

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a main class `Gui` that handles my GUI and calls a few SwingWorkers (calls to DB and other data sources) that have been put in their own class `TablesDataManager`. My issue is that when one of those swingworkers throws an exception within its done90 method (i.e. on the EDT), I want to be able to catch it somehow in the main class and act accordingly (call `showErrorAndExit` in my SSCCE below).

Any ideas would be welcome.

Gui.java

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private final JLabel waitLabel = new JLabel();
    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private final TablesDataManager tblData = new TablesDataManager();

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Gui frame = new Gui("My Great GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Gui(String title) {
        super(title);
        panel.add(waitLabel);
        setContentPane(panel);
        try {
            initData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showErrorAndExit(e);
        }
    }

    //I WANT TO CALL THIS METHOD IF done() THROWS AN EXCEPTION
    private void showErrorAndExit(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                "An unexpected error occured while initialising the tables. The application will close.\n"
                + (e.getMessage() == null ? "" : e.getMessage()),
                "Unrecoverable error",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    }

    private void initData() {
        waitLabel.setText("Loading Data");
        tblData.initData(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                initTables();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initTables() {
        waitLabel.setText("Loading Tables");
        tblData.initTables(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                finishComponentsSetup();
            }
        });
    }

    private void finishComponentsSetup() {
        waitLabel.setText("We are done");
    }
}
```

TablesDataManager.java

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

class TablesDataManager {

    private final InitData initData = new InitData();
    private final InitTables initTables = new InitTables();

    void initData(final Runnable runAfterInit) {
        launchWorker(initData, runAfterInit);
    }

    void initTables(final Runnable runAfterInit) {
        launchWorker(initTables, runAfterInit);
    }

    private void launchWorker(final SimpleSwingWorker worker, final Runnable runAfterWorkerDone) {
        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("progress")) {
                    if (worker.getProgress() == 100) { //update finished
                        runAfterWorkerDone.run();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        worker.execute();
    }

    private class InitData extends SimpleSwingWorker {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            //do something in the background
            //unfortunately there is a connection problem
            throw new IOException("Can't connect to database...");
        }
    }

    private class InitTables extends SimpleSwingWorker {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            //do something else in the background
            return null;
        }
    }


    private abstract class SimpleSwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>  {

        @Override
        protected abstract Void doInBackground() throws Exception;

        @Override
        public void done() {
            try {
                get();
                setProgress(100);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Got that?");
                //WHAT DO I DO WITH IT???
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [somehow I disregarded this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-threa), naming threads, naming, naming depends of Exceptions type otherwise you can lost reference, hmmm I disagreed with answers here

Comment: use [Executor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6174462/714968) with limited number of concurently running thread

Comment: @mKorbel thanks for the link(s) - I'll have a look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep a reference to your workers in your GUI and in your workes add a try catch. In the catch assign the exception to a variable and add a getter to it. IN your GUI, when your worker is done, just check if there is an exception in the worker or not.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative (with slightly lower coupling) I'm nowadays playing with is to let the worker fire a propertyChange with the exception as newValue

```
@Override
protected void done() {
    try {
        get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        firePropertyChange("done-exception", null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know I tried that but could not find a way to catch the change properly when an Exception actually occured. I'll have a look again. Thanks.

Comment: hmm ... you mean like it wasn't fired to the PropertyChangeListener? If so, I would be interested in the outcome of your looking again, could well be that I'm overlooking something :-)

Comment: Something like that yes - but I did not spent much time on it as Guillaume proposed his solution which was simple and efficient.