# How to I join an existing SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I have a Java GUI application that manages a separate serial protocol thread.  The nature of the applications is such that I need to flash text fields when data in the protocol data thread changes - think of part of the live data monitor that looks at steady frames of data that changes over time.  The way I currently handle the animated view is via a custom SwingWorker (shown as the ComponentAnimator in the sample code below which animates lists of Swing objects that implement the AnimatableComponent - essentially just Text Fields for the purpose of my application) which is fired from the event thread the bound protocol data data changes.  The SwingWorker flashes a Text component (reversing the foreground and background text N times with a specified duration between flashes).  This is a crude form of animation that works well when the data in the protocol changes slowly.

The problem that I need help solving concerns when the data in the background protocol thread changes rapidly, the ComponentAnimator starts (via the Executor service which I limited to a pool of three concurrent threads) to queue up rapidly and the animation continues longer than the changing data.  I was wondering if there was some way in the GUI thread (where I fire off the ComponentAnimator) that I could instead join an existing active one, canceling its animation actions and replacing them with the new ones rather than queuing up another timed animation after the current one.  Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

```
/**
 * Handles bound Frame Info property.  For this particular panel,
 * the frameInfo may be associated with this Simulator (Panel)
 * or from frames received from the Prosim737 translated TCP
 * strings.
 *
 * @param aNewFrameInfo
 *               new frame of 429 words
 * @param aOldFrameInfo
 *               old frame of 429 words - if this is null
 *               then this represents the first time
 *               callback of that frame.  This is particularly
 *               important when processing the first Prosim737
 *               Frame for the indicator bits as we must ensure
 *               that we update all indicator bits.  For
 *               subsequent frames we are only interested in
 *               deltas.
 */
private void handleNewFrameData(
    final ProsimLabelInfo aNewFrameInfo,
    final ProsimLabelInfo aOldFrameInfo) {
    // log the event to the log area (this is done in the EVT queue)
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // log changes, don't need a verbose date
            // SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
            java.util.Date lastLogTimeStamp = (aOldFrameInfo == null)?
                aNewFrameInfo.getTimeStamp() : aOldFrameInfo.getTimeStamp();
            // Code added to handle updating the widgets to default when
            // this is the first callback to handleNewFrameData (i.e
            // when aOldFrameInfo null)
            java.util.Date deltaT = new java.util.Date(
                aNewFrameInfo.getTimeStamp().getTime() -
                lastLogTimeStamp.getTime());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                "DT" + gTimeFormat.format(deltaT));
            // make sure we behave like tail -f by setting the caretPosition
            // to the end of the stream of data
            StyledDocument doc = jEventLogTextPane.getStyledDocument();
            // only print changed label details
            boolean bFromPanel = aNewFrameInfo.isFromPanel();
            for (Base429Word newWord : aNewFrameInfo.getDataWords().values()) {
                List<AnimatableComponent> flashingText = new ArrayList<>();
                // get the corresponding label from
                // the previous frame update if any
                Base429Word oldWord = (aOldFrameInfo == null)? null :
                    aOldFrameInfo.get429Word(newWord.getUniqueKey());
                // update GUI elements - if first time word encountered
                if (oldWord == null || !oldWord.equals(newWord)) {
                    processUpdatedWord(bFromPanel, oldWord, newWord);
                    if ((oldWord == null) || !newWord.equals(oldWord)) {
                        JTextComponent textField = bFromPanel? 
                            gTXLabelCompInfo.get(newWord.getUniqueKey()):
                            gRXLabelCompInfo.get(newWord.getUniqueKey());
                        if (textField != null) {
                            flashingText.add(new TextFieldAnimator(
                                textField,
                                Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE,   // final colors
                                Color.YELLOW, Color.RED));  // animating colors
                        }
                    }                        
                    if (flashingText.size() > 0) {
                        // flash first time or changed received words
                        mExecutorService.execute(
                            new ComponentAnimator(flashingText, 1, 70));
                    }                        
                }                    
            }
            // red for changed areas, blue for timestamp prefix
            try {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), sb.toString(), gBlueTextAttrs);
                jEventLogTextPane.setCaretPosition(doc.getLength());
                if ( !jSaveLogButton.isEnabled() ) {
                    jSaveLogButton.setEnabled(true);
                    jClearEventLogButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {}
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to I join an existing SwingWorker

- `SwingWorker` isn't shareable, because is designated to runs as single instance, there isn't non_hacky way(s) to pass value from one instance to another (meaning from `publish()`, `process()`, `setProgress()`), because ther isn't implemented something applicable from `getProgress()`
- this is job for standard threading
- threading with semaphore, but all output to the already visible Swing GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater`, only to methods implemented in AWT, Swing, not whole methods generated this output
- you can to invoke `SwingWorker` from `Executor` and start 2nd. (any number of instances) instance with passing value from `SwingWorker`s instance that ended in `done()`
- for example

  1) for semaphore you would [need to naming SwingWorkers instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-threa)

  2) [another reference code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6186188/714968)

  3) note add [PropertyChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html), .... there isn't implemented any AWT, Swing Listener