# ExecutorService and SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, swingworker, executors

I have looked all over for this answer, but can not seem to find it, so apologies if this is a dumb question. Please be gentle.

I am writing a simple MVC framework, and am getting confused on `SwingWorker` and how it works with `ExecutorService`.

I want to limit the number of threads which ExecutorService permits me to by using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n)`.

I understand the importance of using SwingWorker as it has methods for performing a lengthy task (`doInBackground`...etc) and allows changes to the GUI via the Event Dispatch Thread.

However, creating `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n)` limits the number of threads to `n` whereas `SwingWorker` seems to have a limit of 10 threads set by some kind of private internal constant `MAX_WORKER_THREADS`.

What I want to know am I barking up the wrong tree trying to combine these two classes to limit the number of threads, as the implication seems to be if I submit a `SwingWorker` task to an `Executor`, will that one task spawn up to ten threads?

My eventual aim is to write a program which will have some intensive computations, and I do not want to make such a fundamental error from the outset, as this could prove to be a resourcing consumption problem, that is, I will have a lovely responsive GUI by proper use of the EDT, but then it will become unresponsive if each task is spawning up to 10 threads of its own!

Comment: there is one bug with Executor & SwingWorker, occasionally is there depends of Java version (1.6_015, 1.6_022), but is possible to catch this issue only when you oveloading max threads (12), then SwingWorker not ended(in done()), by default is non_sence to limit number of threads, because there isn't any guarantee that all ended in done() in expected time

Comment: my view about [Executor & SwingWorker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6186188/714968) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053865/cant-get-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-from-future-and-swingworker-if-threa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How does `SwingWorker` work with `ExecutorService`?

- Swing maintains an internal `ExecutorService` instance which is used
  to execute tasks that you submit via `SwingWorker` mechanism.
- I believe that the instantiation of the `ExecutorService` is hidden as it is part of `SwingWorker` implementation and you may not edit it.
- But at the same time, since `SwingWorker` implements `Runnable`, you can submit it to your own `ExecutorService` instance.
- If you call `execute()` method, then it will be scheduled to it's own `ExecutorService`. Instead, you can manually submit the `SwingWorker` instance to your own `ExecutorService`.

### If I submit a `SwingWorker` task to an Executor, will that one task spawn up to ten threads?

- No. To understand this, you should go through `ExecutorService`
  documentation. One task will only use one thread (unless you
  specifically program multithreaded task).
- Other threads are kept in idle by `ExecutorService`. This consumes almost no CPU time.
- If 10 GUI events occur simultaneously, each will be assigned to each of the available thread. If the thread is not required, it will not be running.
- If number of tasks is more than number of threads available, they will be scheduled in a queue by the `ExecutorService` itself.

Hope this clears the doubts. Usually it is a good idea to use default implementation (it works very well), but you easily can limit number of threads if you want. Also, it will not replace Swing's `ExecutorService`. Since it is already there, it's best to use it instead of creating another.

Good Luck.

Comment: Executor doesn't know (nor care about) anything about if is SwingWorker executed nor ended, three black holes used together Executor, Future and SwingWorker

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your point. Are you suggesting SwingWorkers should be avoided in general or SwingWorkers with custom ExecutorService? Last line of the SwingWorker documentation is "Because SwingWorker implements Runnable, a SwingWorker can be submitted to an Executor for execution."

Comment: there are two choices for you 1. this forum loves SwingWorker, 2. but I'm in different view is just for personal enjoy, never for production code, because you haven't any (real) control (excluding cancel()) about code flow, doeasn't matter if is there plain SwingWorker or SwingWorker invoked from Executor, again Executor, Future and SwingWorker are (one of top ten) three biggest wasters in Java

Comment: sure nothing against your answer here

Comment: Posting a `SwingWorker` to an `ExecutorService` is a great idea.